# IOS - Independant Developer for inhouse distribution - code signin

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, in-house-distribution

I have a small company and we should deliver an ios app for an Inhouse distribution OVER THE AIR.
The client have added our apple account into their team as member.
We have terminated the dev process. Thus, they have provided us with their corporate distribution certificate and a provisioning profile.

The problem is that their mobile provision profile is not signed withing our CSR, thus, organiser say that we we have code signing issues.

We thought that for inhouse distribution, our developers MUST deploy app for archiving (ipa generating) on the computers of the client.
My question:
Is there a way to code sign the corporate certificate with the developer CSR? otherwise we won't be able to publish!

Comment: did they sent you their exported distribution certificate? (with .p12 extension)

Comment: No, what is that, in all distribution step by step tutorials none mentioned this... plz develop your idea

Comment: They have to export their distribution certificate from their mac keychain. It is exported with the .p12 extension, they have to send it to you and the password they used to export it. Then you double click on the .p12 and it will ask you the password and import the certificate into your machine